# Is there exactly one healing/revive/save crystal per level?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I've only delved down into level 3 so far, but both the first and second floors had just one healing crystal each. I'm wondering if I can always rely on finding one on each level.

So, are there any levels without crystals, or are there larger levels that have more than one?

If there *are* any deviant levels that ruin your perfectly good yes/no answer, please hide the list behind spoiler tags to maintain the surprise for those who don't want to know exactly what to expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every level had exactly one or zero crystals. Details are below.

> Levels 1-10 had one crystal.
>  Levels 11 and 12 have no healing crystals.
>  Level 13 does have a healing crystal, but it's in a secret area so might be missed, unlike the others on levels 1-10 which are almost impossible to miss.

Comment: I'd argue a spoiler tag is unnecessary since anyone clicking on this question likely did it *specifically because they want to know the answer*, but I did it anyway.

Comment: That's probably true, but no harm done, eh? :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually Level 1 I found 2 crystals so far.

Comment: Hey, Slyvnr, welcome to Arqade!  Can you expand on your answer a bit?  Maybe add what kind of crystals did you find, and where?